# Storing Dropdown Selection of Different Translation on Database - Moodle

Tags: php, mysql, moodle

So I've created Moodle plugin which has 2 localization. In the plugin's form, I have a selector which is translated according to the chosen localization. I wonder if I do this, will cause the stored information on the database mixed? If it does, is there a method to ensure the database will be saved in only 1 language, or if I should translate it in the script before storing it, or even create a translated database altogether? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

It would have been better if you had explained more about the use of the dropdown menu and database details. by the way, let's assume that you need to create a menu to select a job title from among different titles. These job titles are stored in a table with **id** and **title** columns.
In your frontend client can see the **job titles** in their local language and choose the desired option, and finally, you will save the **id** associated with the selected job title into a database table along with other input values that come from your HTML form.

```
<datalist>
  <option name='job' value="id-1">developer</option>
  <option name='job' value="id-2">HR</option>
     ....
</datalist>
```

Answer (score 0):

Moodle already has localisation. If you want display text in different languages, then you need to add a file in your plugin for that language.

In your code you would use a string tag

```
$options = array();
$options[1] = get_string('optionone', 'my_plugin')
$options[2] = get_string('optiontwo', 'my_plugin')
```

You will also need a language file for English as the default

File location

```
my_plugin/lang/en/my_plugin.php
```

Then add the string tags

```
$string['optionone'] = 'Option One';
$string['optiontwo'] = 'Option Two';
```

Then you can add more languages eg

```
my_plugin/lang/fr/my_plugin.php

$string['optionone'] = 'Option Un';
$string['optiontwo'] = 'Option Deux';
```

For more details see

https://docs.moodle.org/dev/String_API